# springframework ldap core propblem with java modules

Tags: java, ldap, java-11, spring-ldap, java-module

Had this kind of problem with main java module.

```
rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapContextSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ldap/embedded/EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource]: Factory method 'ldapContextSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource (in module spring.ldap.core) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory (in module java.naming) because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to module spring.ldap.core
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at app/com.test.app.App.main(App.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource]: Factory method 'ldapContextSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource (in module spring.ldap.core) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory (in module java.naming) because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to module spring.ldap.core
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource (in module spring.ldap.core) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory (in module java.naming) because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to module spring.ldap.core
    at spring.ldap.core@2.3.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.(AbstractContextSource.java:77) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot.autoconfigure@2.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.embedded.EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration.ldapContextSource(EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration.java:93) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at spring.beans@5.2.2.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 18 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I understand whats wrong, but is there any workaround for this, besides remove module-info.java from main module ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do understand the error specifically when it reads in details the following:

> module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to module
>   spring.ldap.core

You can then formulate the workaround for this to provide access using modifiers  as JVM options via the command line:

```
--add-exports java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=spring.ldap.core
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but everything turned normal after I switched to Java 11.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I wanted to upgrade to Java 17. But when I updated the spring-ldap-core dependency to the latest, it worked fine.

Comment: this answer works absolutely fine, as long as you haven't declared Java modules. In the latter case, Naman's answer's viable

Comment: thanks work for me, with java 17 just add next dependency ->                     <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.1</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when running an integration test. All I had to do was exclude the `LdabAutoConfiguration.class` from Spring automatic configuration, like this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {LdapAutoConfiguration.class})
class MyApplicationTestIT { ... }
```