# Problem with Spring and LDAP cant consume that

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap

I take off some part of code from this code:

```
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-ldap
```

with idea of get a simple LDAP CRUD...

My result is 3 class:

**AppConfig**

```
@Configuration
//@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"cl.app.**"})
@Profile("default")
//@EnableLdapRepositories(basePackages = "cl.app.**")
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    
    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        String dir = "ldap.funcionarios.";
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();        
        contextSource.setUrl(env.getProperty(dir + "host") + ":" + env.getProperty(dir + "port"));
        contextSource.setBase(env.getRequiredProperty(dir + "base-dn"));
        contextSource.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty(dir + "username"));
        contextSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(dir + "password"));
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapClient ldapClient() {
        return new LdapClient();
    }

}
```

**LdapCLient**

```
@Service
public class LdapClient {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private ContextSource contextSource;

    @Autowired
    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    public void authenticate(final String username, final String password) {
        contextSource.getContext("cn=" + username + ",ou=users," + env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.partitionSuffix"), password);
    }

    public List<String> search(final String username) {
        return ldapTemplate.search(
          "ou=users",
          "cn=" + username,
          (AttributesMapper<String>) attrs -> (String) attrs
          .get("cn")
          .get());
    }

    public void create(final String username, final String password) {
        Name dn = LdapNameBuilder
          .newInstance()
          .add("ou", "users")
          .add("cn", username)
          .build();
        DirContextAdapter context = new DirContextAdapter(dn);

        context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "inetOrgPerson" });
        context.setAttributeValue("cn", username);
        context.setAttributeValue("sn", username);
        context.setAttributeValue("userPassword", digestSHA(password));

        ldapTemplate.bind(context);
    }

    public void modify(final String username, final String password) {
        Name dn = LdapNameBuilder
          .newInstance()
          .add("ou", "users")
          .add("cn", username)
          .build();
        DirContextOperations context = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(dn);

        context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "inetOrgPerson" });
        context.setAttributeValue("cn", username);
        context.setAttributeValue("sn", username);
        context.setAttributeValue("userPassword", digestSHA(password));

        ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context);
    }

    private String digestSHA(final String password) {
        String base64;
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            digest.update(password.getBytes());
            base64 = Base64
              .getEncoder()
              .encodeToString(digest.digest());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return "{SHA}" + base64;
    }
}
```

**MyController**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    
    @Autowired
    LdapClient ldap;

    @RequestMapping("/new")
    @ResponseBody
    public String create() {
        System.out.println("Agregar Usuario");
        
        ldap.create("NewUser", "1234");       
        return "create";
    }
```

**Dependencies**

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--  LDAP Dependencies  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

when i run get the followins errors

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ldap'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapClient': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'contextSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource' defined in class path resource [cl/app/config/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource]: Factory method 'contextSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource (in unnamed module @0x121314f7) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory (in module java.naming) because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to unnamed module @0x121314f7
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at cl.app.LdapConectApplication.main(LdapConectApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapClient': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'contextSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource' defined in class path resource [cl/app/config/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource]: Factory method 'contextSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource (in unnamed module @0x121314f7) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory (in module java.naming) because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to unnamed module @0x121314f7
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource' defined in class path resource [cl/app/config/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource]: Factory method 'contextSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource (in unnamed module @0x121314f7) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory (in module java.naming) because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to unnamed module @0x121314f7
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource]: Factory method 'contextSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource (in unnamed module @0x121314f7) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory (in module java.naming) because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to unnamed module @0x121314f7
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource (in unnamed module @0x121314f7) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory (in module java.naming) because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to unnamed module @0x121314f7
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.<clinit>(AbstractContextSource.java:77) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at cl.app.config.AppConfig.contextSource(AppConfig.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at cl.app.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4e54f82.CGLIB$contextSource$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at cl.app.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4e54f82$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$be4e1a9b.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at cl.app.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4e54f82.contextSource(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

if i take off the next dependency or update version to 2.4.1, run correctly but cant do that because is requeried for other part of service and cant change the version....

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

in resume i need repair the code for run with org.springframework.ldap  version 2.3.3.RELEASE...

any suggestions ?..

Thanks everyone !..

Comment: looks like you need to add a parameter to java check https://stackoverflow.com/a/60748032/175554